# Cant work out bug with my Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I can't get the total price to show up on the screen. I am sure this is just a small bug somewhere but I can't find it.

```js
var cabbage_prices = new Array();
cabbage_prices["Round6"]=20;
cabbage_prices["Round8"]=25;
cabbage_prices["Round10"]=35;
cabbage_prices["Round12"]=75;

var filling_prices= new Array();
filling_prices["None"]=0;
filling_prices["Lemon"]=5;
filling_prices["Custard"]=5;
filling_prices["Fudge"]=7;
filling_prices["Mocha"]=8;
filling_prices["Raspberry"]=10;
filling_prices["Pineapple"]=5;
filling_prices["Dobash"]=9;
filling_prices["Mint"]=5;
filling_prices["Cherry"]=5;
filling_prices["Apricot"]=8;
filling_prices["Buttercream"]=7;
filling_prices["Chocolate Mousse"]=12;


function getCabbageSizePrice()
{  
  var cabbageSizePrice=0;
  var theForm = document.forms["cabbageForm"];
  var selectedCabbage = theForm.elements["selectedcabbage"];
  for(var i = 0; i < selectedCabbage.length; i++)
  {
    if(selectedCabbage[i].checked)
    {
      cabbageSizePrice = cabbage_prices[selectedCabbage[i].value];
      break;
    }
  }
  return cabbageSizePrice;
}

function getFillingPrice()
{
  var cabbageFillingPrice=0;

  var theForm = document.forms["cabbageform"];
  var selectedFilling = theForm.elements["filling"];
  cabbageFillingPrice = filling_prices[selectedFilling.value];
  return cabbageFillingPrice;
}


function calculateTotal()
{
  var cabbagePrice = getCabbageSizePrice() + getFillingPrice();
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display='block';
  divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Cabbage $"+cabbagePrice;

}

function hideTotal()
{
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display='none';
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <form action="" id="cabbageform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>
      <div class="cont_order">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Order Your Cabbages</legend>
          <label >Size of your Cabbage</label>
          <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcabbage" value="Round6" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Round Cabbage 6" -  serves 3 people ($20)</label><br/>
          <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcabbage" value="Round8" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Round Cabbage 8" - serves 5 people ($25)</label><br/>
          <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcabbage" value="Round10" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Round Cabbage 10" - serves 10 people($35)</label><br/>
          <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcabbage" value="Round12" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Round Cabbage 12" - serves 15 people($75)</label><br/>
          <br/>
          <label >Cabbage Filling</label>

          <select id="filling" name='filling' onchange="calculateTotal()">
            <option value="None">Select Filling</option>
            <option value="Lemon">Lemon Sauce($5)</option>
            <option value="Custard">Custard Sauce($5)</option>
            <option value="Fudge">Fudge Sauce($7)</option>
            <option value="Mocha">Mocha($8)</option>
            <option value="Raspberry">Raspberry($10)</option>
            <option value="Pineapple">Pineapple($5)</option>
            <option value="Dobash">Dobash($9)</option>
            <option value="Mint">Mint($5)</option>
            <option value="Cherry">Cherry($5)</option>
            <option value="Apricot">Apricot($8)</option>
            <option value="Buttercream">Buttercream($7)</option>
            <option value="Chocolate Mousse">Chocolate Mousse($12)</option>
          </select>
          <br/>            
        </fieldset>
      </div>

      <div class="cont_details">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Contact Details</legend>
          <label for='name'>Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name='name' />
          <br/>
          <label for='address'>Address</label>
          <input type="text" id="address" name='address' />
          <br/>
          <label for='phonenumber'>Phone Number</label>
          <input type="text"  id="phonenumber" name='phonenumber'/>
          <br/>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
    </div>  
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML doesn't have an element with the id 'totalPrice'. Where do you expect the totalprice to be displayed?

Comment: Open the browser's JavaScript console and check the errors there, so you don't have to stare at code for hours trying to guess where the problem is.

Comment: Yeah, there are actually a couple errors here. For example, unless I'm wrong, document.forms["string"] should be document.forms[0] because it accesses a list of all the forms in the document, not whichever named form you specify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You'd better use JQuery for manipulating page elements. Object models are differ in different browsers. So, JQuery script will be universal and easy to write.
2. You'd better use declarative style for setting values (using data-attributes).
3. You'd better subscribe your event handlers in script, not in HTML code.

I fixed your code.

1. I added `<input type="text"  id="total" name='total' readonly="readonly" />` to provide calculation results.
2. My code called on `$(document).ready()` event.

This is shortened equivalent for `$(document).ready()`:

`$(function() { // YOUR JQUERY CODE });`

3. I subscribed for two change events:

`$('#cabbageform input[name="selectedcabbage"]').change(...)`

`$('#cabbageform select[name="filling"]').change(...)`

4. In hanlder I made a search for current form for more universal solution: `var $form = $(this).closest('form');`.
5. I passed this form to our calculation function: `updateTotal($form);`.
6. In `updateTotal()` I looking for checked radiobuttons and selected options and get prices from them:

`$form.find('input[name="selectedcabbage"]:checked').data('price')`

`$form.find('select[name="filling"] option:selected').data('price')`

`data('price')` method returns a value of the `data-price` attribute.

7. If use the value just if it is not NaN (not not a number) – that means it is a number:

`if (!isNaN(selectedcabbage))`

8. I summarize prices and set it to the total input:

`$form.find('input[name="total"]').val(total);`

P.S. Feel free to ask questions if something is not clear for you.

```js
function updateTotal($form)
{  
    var total = 0;

    var selectedcabbage = $form.find('input[name="selectedcabbage"]:checked').data('price');
    if (!isNaN(selectedcabbage))
    {
        total += selectedcabbage;
    }
    
    var filling = $form.find('select[name="filling"] option:selected').data('price');
    if (!isNaN(filling))
    {
        total += filling;
    }
    
    $form.find('input[name="total"]').val(total);
}

$(function() {
    $('#cabbageform input[name="selectedcabbage"]').change(function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        updateTotal($form);
    });

    $('#cabbageform select[name="filling"]').change(function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        updateTotal($form);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
    <form action="" id="cabbageform">
    <div>
        <div class="cont_order">
           <fieldset>
            <legend>Order Your Cabbages</legend>
            <label >Size of your Cabbage</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcabbage" value="Round6" data-price="20" />Round Cabbage 6" -  serves 3 people ($20)</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcabbage" value="Round8" data-price="25" />Round Cabbage 8" - serves 5 people ($25)</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcabbage" value="Round10" data-price="35" />Round Cabbage 10" - serves 10 people($35)</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcabbage" value="Round12" data-price="75" />Round Cabbage 12" - serves 15 people($75)</label><br/>
            <br/>
            <label >Cabbage Filling</label>

            <select id="filling" name='filling'>
            <option value="None">Select Filling</option>
            <option value="Lemon" data-price="5">Lemon Sauce($5)</option>
            <option value="Custard" data-price="5">Custard Sauce($5)</option>
            <option value="Fudge" data-price="7">Fudge Sauce($7)</option>
            <option value="Mocha" data-price="8">Mocha($8)</option>
            <option value="Raspberry" data-price="10">Raspberry($10)</option>
            <option value="Pineapple" data-price="5">Pineapple($5)</option>
            <option value="Dobash" data-price="9">Dobash($9)</option>
            <option value="Mint" data-price="5">Mint($5)</option>
            <option value="Cherry" data-price="5">Cherry($5)</option>
            <option value="Apricot" data-price="8">Apricot($8)</option>
            <option value="Buttercream" data-price="7">Buttercream($7)</option>
            <option value="Chocolate Mousse" data-price="12">Chocolate Mousse($12)</option>
           </select>
            <br/>            
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div class="cont_details">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Contact Details</legend>
            <label for='name'>Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name='name' />
            <br/>
            <label for='address'>Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="address" name='address' />
            <br/>
            <label for='phonenumber'>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text"  id="phonenumber" name='phonenumber'/>
            <br/>
            <label for='total'>Total price</label>
            <input type="text"  id="total" name='total' readonly="readonly" />
            <br/>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' />
    </div>  
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems i still have much to learn with Javascript, but thats okay since i enjoy it. I took a look at your code but it still wont seem to show any prices in the text box, i may have copied something across wrong or am i missing something?

Comment: Have you got any JS errors in console? You could debug your script by printing some data to console by `console.log(...);` in any place of your script. And you could add a special command that pauses your JS and allow you to debug it step-by-step – just insert this line it any place `debugger;`, open developer console in your browser. When script'll got paused, you could run it step-by-step by `F10` and `F11` keys, press `F8` to unpause it.

Comment: Thanks, i think i worked out the problem area. I am getting an error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined' which links me to '$(function()' I tried messing around with it but even after i removed the error still no luck. I also tried debugging with the method you said but it didnt really find anything.

Comment: `$` is a JQuery object. You need to link a JQuery library in `<head>` using `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Or in any other way.

Comment: I already tried that before but still didnt seem to fix anything. Not sure what else the problem could be

Comment: Could you provide full code?
You could use [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to share your code.

Comment: http://codepaste.net/qbs4q6 here you go. I can change it to JSFiddle if its to hard to read. I am new to everything, including linking code haha. Thanks again!

Comment: I copied your code to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whmab2h5/) and it's working. You should remove duplicating `<script src='jquery'>` in `<body>`. And if you've got any errors in your js file `js/formcalculations.js`, script won't work.

Comment: I moved a code to another service, that provides ability to put the whole html file code: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xalayikume/edit?html,js,output).
I've got the same result – it's working.
Remove your external script `js/formcalculations.js` from `<head>` to check. And look whether there are any JS errors in console?

Comment: Still no luck but the fact its working on JSBin is probably a sign that its an error on my side. I wont trouble you anymore with trying to work out what it is, i am going to switch to a different editor since its clearly not picking anything up. Thank you very much for your effort

Comment: Please try to copy code from that JSBin and check it. Always check developer console for errors. If you've got any – provide them here.

Comment: So i copied the code back into my files to make sure it was 100% the same and i am back to getting the 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined' error in the '$(function() {' I know we fixed it before, so im nto sure why its back

Comment: You could call me via skype (find it in my profile) and show your screen. I'll help you to deal with it.

Comment: I would love to but my internet wont be good enough to share screen, plus you have honestly done enough for me, i will feel bad if you go out of your way any more.
I will try it on a different computer and editor and see if it works

Comment: It's not connected with computer or editor. I think there is a quite simple error. Not good to spent time to solve this issue and give up at the end :-) Let's try skype screenshare. Or send me archive of your code.

Comment: I tried to play around with it for a while longer but still no luck, here is the link to the archive files:    http://www.mediafire.com/download/3ens0k3n73ad2sx/CabbageCode.rar

Comment: @Xarigizel You just need to link your `js/formcalculations.js` file after linking a JQuery library. That is a source of the `$ is not defined` error. Resource linking order is important. You could not use `$` (JQuery object) before you have it loaded and created.